# how to color unstructured grid (.vtu) in vtk?

Tags: c#, colors, interpolation, vtk, paraview

My whole source code is present [here](https://github.com/learning-hide/vtktest) including [block.vtu](https://github.com/learning-hide/vtktest/tree/main/vtktest/vtktest/bin/x86/Debug) file for testing purpose. I will discuss important functions here.

This code can color *.vtp, *.vtk.
But same code fails to color *.vtu.

I have list of **vtkactors**. And I specify which **actor** to set properties from.

1. This code which **gets all column names from an actor**:

```cs
public static List<string> getColumns(int actorIndex)
{
    List<string> colums = new List<string>();
    vtkActor actor = actors[actorIndex];
    var output = actor.GetMapper().GetInputAsDataSet();
    var cell = output.GetCellData();
    for (int i = 0; i < cell.GetNumberOfArrays(); i++)
    {
        var colm = cell.GetArrayName(i);
        if (colm != null) colums.Add(colm);
    }
    return colums; //['CU_OK','D1','Domain','IJK','IX','IY'...]
}
```

2. This code **colors the model of specific column**:

```cs
public static void setColors(int actorIndex, string column)
{
    List<string> colums = new List<string>();
    vtkActor actor = actors[actorIndex];
    var output = actor.GetMapper().GetInputAsDataSet();
    var colors = vtkUnsignedCharArray.New();
    colors.SetNumberOfComponents(3);
    colors.SetName("Colors");

    var cell = output.GetCellData();
    for (int i = 0; i < cell.GetNumberOfArrays(); i++)
    {
        var cells = cell.GetArray(i);
        if (cells == null) continue;
        if (column != cell.GetArrayName(i)) continue;
        for (int j = 0; j < cells.GetNumberOfTuples(); j++)
        {
            var c = color_range((cells.GetComponent(i, j) / cell.GetArray(i).GetRange()[1]) * 100);
            var R = c.R;
            var G = c.G;
            var B = c.B;
            colors.InsertNextTuple3((double)R, (double)G, (double)B);
            colors.InsertNextTuple3((double)R, (double)G, (double)B);  //even tried with and without inserting second tuple
        }

    }
    output.GetPointData().SetScalars(colors); //even tried with GetCellData(), but no luck
}
```

3. This code **gets range(min,max) of values from specific column**:

```cs
public static double[] getRange(int actorIndex, string column)
{
    List<string> colums = new List<string>();
    vtkActor actor = actors[actorIndex];
    var output = actor.GetMapper().GetInputAsDataSet();
    var cell = output.GetCellData();
    for (int i = 0; i < cell.GetNumberOfArrays(); i++)
    {
        var colm = cell.GetArrayName(i);
        var arr = cell.GetArray(i);
        if (column == colm)
        {
            if (arr == null) return null;
            return arr.GetRange(); // new double[] { min, max }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

#### ACTUAL OUTPUT for VTP and VTK (GOOD):

The result is fine. This is how drillholes are shown in by my code.
[image: colored drillhole]

#### EXPECTED OUTPUT for VTU (GOOD):

See how its colored. This is what PARAVIEW software can show:
[image: Paraview Block Model]

#### ACTUAL OUTPUT for VTU (BAD):

This is how my code show that model:
[image: My Block Model]

#### I also tried:

I tried following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68065472/19697618), but vtu color has no effect.
I tried cell data too instead of point data.
I also tried lookup table, it do shows with color scalebar but has no effect on model color.

The strange things are that:

- all vtp files work (to color)and all vtu files fails
- vtu file show colorful fine on paraview, but not in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a proper solution, but it might work if you create a new mapper at the end of the `setColors` function.

```
            output.GetPointData().SetScalars(colors);

+           vtkDataSetMapper mapper = vtkDataSetMapper.New();
+           mapper.SetInput(output);
+           actor.SetMapper(mapper);
        }
```